# Windows 10 - I want to set environment variable for D drive

Tags: environment-variables

This is what I mean by "I set up the environment variable for d drive

[image]

I am using windows 10 and I have installed Kafka in D drive. So when I set up the environment variable for d drive it does not work. I want to know if is it even possible to set an environment variable for something present in D drive?
So basically I want to run kafka server and for that I am setting path of kafka directory in environment variables.
There are many bat files in kafka directory,which i need to run.
So once this environment variable is set. I can use these kafka commands from anywhere and don't need to open my command prompt in kafka directory only.

I hope now i have provided enough information.
It should work like this:
In cmd: when i type kafka-server-start.bat ./config/server.properties it should start this server.

Comment: "when I set up the environment variable for d drive" - what does this mean? Describe the steps you take with the exact commands you used, and any error messages that you see.

Comment: I have updated with image in question,please chekc that

Comment: You are providing very little information about what you are trying to do. Are your trying to add a directory to your "path" environment variable? There's no reason why that should not work for something on the D: drive. What do you mean when you say "it does not work"? What are you trying to do and what is the problem you run into? Are there any error messages? Is there some installation/setup manual that you're following? If so, please add a link to it.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Is there an executable program or script in that actual folder (not a sub folder) that you are expecting to run just by using its name? Does the folder exist? Please clarify.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this problem is non-reproducible: "It worked when I restarted my pc."

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I restarted my pc.